# How to make make logo bigger?

Tags: css, html

I cant seem to make my homepage logo(the one in top center) bigger. Eshop forces it to be 100x100.

https://www.gallery.amres.art/

Thank you.

Comment: Please post some relevant code, not a link to your website.

Comment: Introduce your question. Just telling us that you can't seem do do something is not enough. Describe specifically what you are asking and show us enough of what you have tried including your code so that we can understand how to respond with a good answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I think that the CSS on your project is a little broken, and it should be changed so the content is not floating, and the elements will be pushing the another to the bottom.

Nonetheless, you can add this to your CSS styles, and it looks like it can help you:

```css
#header-wrap {
  height: 180px;
}
a#logo > img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Hope it does!

Answer (score -1):

The Problem here is your container. The image es greater than the container. Make the container heigher :)

Answer (score -1):

If it is about the following snippet / image you just have to change the width / height within your html

```
<img src="https://www.gallery.amres.art/images/uploader/am/500x100/amres-art-logo-su-melynu-sukiu-1.png" height="100" width="100" alt="Amres Art" title="Amres Art">
```